# Having questions as field name in database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I was wondering if it ok to use a question as a field name or column on a table such as IsTheWetherNiceOutsite? is there any pros or cons, or is there any other way to archive this?

Comment: I don't know if you can use the question mark, but why not just call it `weather_nice` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd avoid column names with special characters like `?` in the table itself.  Writing queries can get troublesome.

But you can use column aliases if you want.  For example,

```
SELECT NOW() 'What time is it?',
       t.weatherNice 'Is the weather nice?'
  FROM table t
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. The `is` prefix already indicating that it's a boolean flag.

Prefer not to use weird characters, it *might* work (if use use backticks for the column name), but might not be portable, and will certainly confuse others.